# SASS/Compass style checker

Tags: css, styles, sass, compass-sass

In a company where are work we're trying to automate build processes and testing and we've got all covered except for SASS/Compass style checker. Note that I'm not talking about checking for syntax errors, but about checking against some sort of style guide - indentation, spacing line-length, etc.

I've been searching for similar software for a while now but I'm either bad at searching or google doesn't have all the answers. Only condition is that it can be run from unix command line.

Any help or clue is more than welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if there is a tool that will allow you to do that but another way you can tackle this is by setting every developer's text editors to follow the same guidelines. (spaces vs tabs, tab length, etc..)

Comment: to follow on with the suggestion from @DeviantSeev , [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org) might be handy.

Comment: Thanks for EditorConfig, it seems handy, but it's just a part of the solution as we want the code to be checked in pre-commit hook, as we currently do with PHP Code sniffer and Closure linter.

Comment: I just realized that EditorConfig can be used as command line utility and, although it's not 100% what we need, it will do the job. 

Manu thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [SCSS-Lint](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint) does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to control the input scss or sass files, or just the output?

If you are after layout control of the Compass produced stylesheets (in other words - the end result), and if you run compass with ruby, you can choose the "output_style" in the config.rb file from the following:-

```
:expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
```

I mostly use :compact which removes all the tab vs spaces and newline issues, while keeping the file easily readable.

As for style checking the original scss or sass files, I have not seen anything in my travels other than EditorConfig as @steveax commented.

I would have just commented on this one, but not enough points yet :( Hope this helps.

Comment: We already use different output styles in css, but we want to enforce the same style guide among all developers. We've done so for php and javascript using PHP Code Sniffer and Google Closure linter, respectively.